# I am trying to activate the Vector skin in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I have set up a wiki on a hosted server. Whenever I go to the wiki, this is what I see:

[image]

I have followed the instructions, but the skin still doesn't get installed. What can I do? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you don't actually have the Vector skin installed (the error message you show lists all available skins in your installation, and Vector isn't there). Can you please spell out what you've done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Add the line `wfLoadSkin('vector');` to your `LocalSettings.php` file.